# Sandcastle Help File Builder Project not showing up in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I installed SHFBInstaller_v2017.5.15.0.zip from https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases. After going through the guided installation I launched Visual Studio, opened an already existing C# console application, and when I went to add a new project to the solution, there was not Sandcastle Help File Builder project listed. Here are the options I can see in visual studio:

[image]

I restarted my computer to see if that would fix anything but it didn't. I'm not sure why I am experiencing this problem. I've used sandcastle before and didn't experience this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is in the Documentation category. The Visual C# category is for C# coded projects, which Sandcastle documentation is not.